# Unknown property 'SoqlExample.accs' I am new to slalesforce getting this error

Tags: visualforce

```html
<apex:page  controller="SoqlExample">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="SoqlResult">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!a.industry}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## Controller:

```java
public class SoqlExample{
    list<account>  accs {get;set;}
    public  SoqlExample(){
        accs =[select id,name,industry from Account]; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks likely that it is because the property "accs" is private (default scope). Make it public.

Comment: By the way, if you are new to Salesforce I recommend you skip playing with the old technology (Visualforce) and move directly to LWC. Visualforce was replaced by Lightning Aura which itself has now been replaced by LWC.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access attributes on your controller which have a public getter. There is a wide variety of methods to do so, but the simplest would be to just specify `public` on your entire attribute:

```
public List<Account> accs { get; set; }
```

While this change is the simplest, however, you should be cognizant of having a public setter, and only do so when you actually expect the page to set the attribute in question (not possible here). So instead, you should use `private set`.

```
public List<Account> accs { get; private set; }
```

There are other viable syntactic approaches as well, but it is not necessary to know all of them.